# Simple C++ quadratic Equation solver returning incorrect answers

Tags: c++, equation, quadratic

I'm working on a school assignment that requires using the quadratic equation to find the roots of ax^2+bx+c=0, with a b & c as inputs.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int a, b, c;

   cout << "Enter coefficients a b c: " << endl;
   cin >> a >> b >> c;
   double r1, r2;

   r1=((-1)*b+sqrt(b*b-4*a*c))/2*a;

   r2=((-1)*b-sqrt(b*b-4*a*c))/2*a;


   cout << "The roots are: " << r1 << " and " << r2 << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

However, when I input 2 -8 8, the correct answer is 2 and 2, but I am getting 8 and 8 after running the program. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are missing parentheses around `(2*a)`. Voting to close as a "simple typo". Note: `-1*b` can be written as simply `-b`.

Answer (score 1):

Your program is actually multiplying the solution by `a` instead of dividing it. (This is why it is off by a factor of 4)

```
r1 = (((-1)*b+sqrt(b*b-4*a*c))/2)*a);
```

Try putting a pair of parenthesis around the 2*a:

```
r1=((-1)*b+sqrt(b*b-4*a*c))/(2*a);
```

Comment: Wow I should've noticed that. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark the answer as accepted so others know that you managed to solve it :)